# Window Service when folder copying is finished

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a server location path like `\\10.100.100.10000\Builds`. Whenever somebody fires a force build in our server in Visual Studio, a new build folder, like `2013.1.3.1`, gets created and new files are copied into it. I need to write a `Windows Service` so when the folder gets copied completely, I need to extract `Application.exe` and do some processing.

My question is how to know if the folder has been copied completely? Googling and Binging did not help me much. Do I have to tell my team who is firing the build event to do some custom work to let my program know that the copying files have finished? Or there is some .Net libraries to accomplish this task?

Comment: How about checking the size of the directory and - if it is not getting any bigger - assuming the copy process succeeded?

Comment: When a solution id building, new files are added and current files are modified. Certainly build size will never be same. This idea will not be suitable.

Comment: In that case observe that folder and if the size isn't changing any more after a timeout do your custom action since the built is complete or define a post build event to invoke your application.

Comment: hmmm....that sounds a good idea. Let me see if my team approves it....will keep you posted with updates.

Comment: I think you could use CruiseControl.Net or something like it, it could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it in the end to see if a folder copying has been finished. Create a `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` and assign a event at `Created` property.

```
private void FileSystemWatcherCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    long sizeOld = GetDirectorySize(new DirectoryInfo(e.FullPath));

    Thread.Sleep(100000);

    long sizeNew = GetDirectorySize(new DirectoryInfo(e.FullPath));

    if (sizeOld == sizeNew)
    {
        // Copying finished.
    }
}
```

The above method just checks the folder size every one minute and then compare the sizes. If sizes are same, declares that copying folder has finished.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a FileSystemWatcher to watch for the activity in the folder, the monitoring could be started when the Windows Service starts (In Start Method).

You could have the following event handlers registered with the FileWatcher

FSWatcher.Deleted += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.FSWatcher_Deleted);
FSWatcher.Renamed += new System.IO.RenamedEventHandler(this.FSWatcher_Renamed);
FSWatcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.FSWatcher_Changed);
FSWatcher.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.FSWatcher_Created);

FSWatcher_Changed event will be kept fired until the copy process finishes.

You could use this event to know when the copy started and wait till the copy process finishes.

Once the copy process is finished, I mean when the folder is quiet, you could start doing the extracting of Application.Exe or any other tasks you would like to do.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Everything you said was know to me. I am just asking how to know if copy process is finished? I mean copying can also happen from a different server through Remote.

Comment: Let’s say you are getting the Changed event fired. You start a timer with let’s say 60 seconds. If the changed event has not fired again within the 60 seconds, you could assume as the copy process is finished and start doing your work. If it is fired again, reset the timer. If you have access to the source folder, you could also do a verification by comparing both source and target folders once the copying finished.

Comment: As long as the FileSystemWatcher is set to watch the folder, and the account has sufficient permissions, you will get the event fired whether the files are copied by a local or remote application.  I have implemented this in a production environment and did not have any problem till now.